# App Engine updating code using rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Hello I want to update my source code on my App Engine using the Google Cloud Platform. I use ruby and the web framework rails. 
To update my source code on the App Engine I can just tap

```
gcloud preview app deploy
```

So my question is do I have to deploy the whole App again to just update few lines of code ?
I already use git but the problem is when I tap

```
git push google master
```

The App Engine not really update my source code. But on git it appears perfectly. I would be really happy if you guys have some tips for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to deploy to app engine using git. You need to run:

```
gcloud  preview app deploy
```